# How to take screenshot in Sony Xperia Neo l without third party app?

Tags: screenshots, sony-xperia-neo-l

Since <kbd>volume-down</kbd> + <kbd>power key</kbd> doesn't work, is it possible to take screenshots on Sony Xperia Neo l? If so, how?

Answer (score 2):

Press and hold <kbd>Power</kbd> button and <kbd>Volume-down</kbd> button exactly at the same time and hold them there until you take a screenshot.(in ICS)

I tried it now. And its working.

Comment: Take a look at the main post ;) The poster explains that vol down+power doesn't work

Comment: He didn't get it work, may be because of timing issue...I tried it and failed so many times, but when I click at same time it works.

Comment: Good point, I thought it was a default feature on Android 4.+ but it may have been disabled or the xperia neo may be on 2.3 I dont know really

Comment: Just checked and it comes with 2.3 upgradeable to 4.0 so maybe on 2.3 still?

Comment: Nope. Neo L is coming with ICS not GingerBread
http://www.gsmarena.com/sony_xperia_neo_l-4647.php

Comment: Wrong tagging as Neo V(it comes with gingerbread)

Comment: @MattLin: There were no [tag:sony-xperia-neo-l] tags, so I had no choice.

Answer (score -1):

Use [monkeyrunner](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/monkeyrunner_concepts.html) or run the DDMS and take a screenshot.

Read more at [How to take screenshots on an Android device](http://theunlockr.com/2011/05/09/how-to-take-screenshots-on-an-android-device/#pKOxXrXdyp7HlgEZ.99).

Comment: I googled it before asking here, I'm interested in tricks where no third party apps is used for that purpose. Thank you for your answer anyway.

Comment: They're not third party apps they are the tools provided by Google for situations like this, I don't understand why anyone would mark down the answer. A third party app would require root access to the device, the tools I linked are from Google

Answer (score -2):

Press Power off and volume key down at the same time for 2 secs...it will take a screen shot..

Comment: How is this different than the solution provided in [this answer](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/40326/267) or [this other answer](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/38136/267)?

Comment: Have you confirmed that this works on the Xperia Neo?

Answer (score -3):

I know this isn't the easiest way but if you are desperate you can do [This](http://www.thefullsignal.com/sony-ericsson/sony-ericsson-xperia-neo/xperia-neo-guides/759262/how_to_take_screenshots_on_the_sony_ericsson_xperia_neo.html)...But before you do that, try hitting the `power` button slightly before you press down the `volume-down` key. If that doesn't work than maybe Sony just overlooked this feature on the update.